# Reference to parent window after allow popup window once

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup

So I'm trying to test whenever popup windows are enabled for my site. My window should be blocked by browser's popup blocker, unless they are already allowed. If popup windows are allowed everything works fine, since I can test whenever the window was opened directly in my parent page.

Problem is that I still want to mark the test as sucessfull if the user allows to open popup window later by allowing the popup window to open. Only way for me to do that is by calling some function on my parent page, but window opened this way has `null window.opener` and I can't set the object on child window directly from my parent window since I don't know when will it open.

Is there any way to get reference to my parent window from child window when it's opened this way?

Or any other workaround that could call function on my parent window whenever the child window is sucessfully opened?
Maybe event event that I could hook up to whenever such window is opened, but I couldn't find any such event.

Sample code:

```
function () {
    var myWin = window.open('popupWin.html', '_blank', 'resizable=no,scrollbars=no,height=1,width=1', true);
    if (!myWin || myWin == null || typeof (myWin) == 'undefined')
        SetPopupResult(false);
    else {
        SetPopupResult(true);
        myWin.close();
    }
}
```

popupWin.html is empty page with following script:

```
    <script>
            window.opener.SetPopupResult(true); //throws Cannot read property 'SetPopupResult' of null
            setTimeout(function () {  
                window.close();
            }, 1000);
    </script>
```

**Edit: Forgot to mention this is issue in Google-Chrome so far, firefox doesn't seem to have this problem and window.opener is correct, IE's behaivor is different as it refreshes the page and openes the popup window like they were enabled.**

Comment: How is the original function called?

Comment: @epascarello It's part of bigger object and is called on page load.

Comment: did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @Crashalot Hi, we didn't find the solution and since the problem was pretty much UI/UX related and only happened in Chrome we ignored it further. The reason why window.opener is null is very likely because when you click in chrome to open the popup, it opens the link with rel="noopener", I quess it is because of security reasons.Workaround would be, if you only need some data and the page is in same domain you could periodically check cookies, localstorage or indexedDB to get that data, if you need reference to the opener I'm affraid there is no way to get it in this case.